# Array of EditText controls

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

It looks like a rather common thing.
I am trying to display a list of EditText controls, like
Label1 EditText1
Label2 EditText2
…
so that user can edit text “in-place”, and this list has to be shown in Dialog (AlertDialog?).
I am using ArrayAdapter to fill the list. The problem is that I can not find the right EditText for its label to get the user-modified values.
BTW, It’s hard to believe how many passes the system makes filling the list with getView(). It is also being called when I click on one of EditText.
Maybe my approach is wrong and there is a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).  Note the use of ViewHolder and how they package groups of elements using a container like class and then set the Views tag to point at that object.  There is an interesting discussion [here](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7767) as well.  To be clear, ViewHolder is just a class you create and define and is more of a pattern then an answer.  But it can provide a performance improvement as well as an organizational improvement in many cases.  The example may give you other insight into what you are working on.

Comment: I already looked at ApiDemos project and could not find the answer. The problem is that each text is in fact EditText. I have no problem to display the list. The question is how to get the user-modified input from the screen. I tried to subclass EditText, but in this case the dialog hangs when I dismiss it.<br>

Comment: When you define the ui in xml are you setting android:id for each element?  If so, you can use View.getId() and compare that to the id of the fields you are trying to find.  If you aren't using xml to define the ui (i would suggest you do) you can use setId() to give the field and id and then use getId to retrieve it.